# Value is missing .default for imported module

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

Fighting with webpack, react and typescript. The core problem is that TS compiled code is referencing a ".default" when the value is on the exported component.

I can either modify the *.d.ts file or I can change the code, but my attempts haven't made much difference. Making it `= require("....")` just yields a type error.

Have the following react file:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Paragraph from 'grommet/components/Paragraph';

export class Footer extends React.Component<Props, any> {
  render() {
    // Works -- return <span>Hello</span>;
    return (
      <Paragraph>
        Hello
      </Paragraph>
    );
  }
}
```

Which transpiles into:

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const React = __webpack_require__(12);
const Paragraph_1 = __webpack_require__(153);
class Footer extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (React.createElement(Paragraph_1.default, null, "Hello"));
    }
}
exports.Footer = Footer;
```

What I note is that Paragraph_1 is the exported function from Grommet, while Paragraph_1.default is undefined.

Paragraph has the following for "exports" --

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});

// Lots of real code here...

Paragraph.displayName = 'Paragraph';
exports.default = Paragraph;
module.exports = exports['default'];
```

The Grommet types.d.ts file says:

```
declare module "grommet/components/Paragraph" {
   export default Grommet.Paragraph;
}
```

And my tsconfig.json file has the following:

```
{
   "compilerOptions" : {
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "importHelpers" : true,

      "target": "es5",
      "noImplicitAny": false,
      "removeComments": true,
      "sourceMap": true,
      "module": "commonjs",
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "outDir": "out",

      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports" : true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "declaration": false,
      "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
      "sourceMap": true,
      "preserveConstEnums": true,
      "noImplicitAny" : true,
      "noEmitOnError" : true,
      "noEmitHelpers" : false,
      "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch" : true,
      "noImplicitReturns" : true,
      "noImplicitThis" : true,
      "experimentalDecorators" : true,
      "strictNullChecks" : true,
      "pretty" : true,
      "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames" : true,

      "jsx": "react",
      "lib" : [
         "dom",
         "es6",
         "es2016",
         "es2017.object"
      ]
   },
   "exclude" : [
      "out",
      "dist",
      "node_modules"
   ],
    "files": [
        "app/index.tsx",
        "types/grommet.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the fix was that I was using `commonjs` modules rather than `es6`.  Changing the following line in my `tsconfig.json` the import problem.

```
  "module": "es6",
```

Comment: Hey Koblas, I'm assuming you're not running this code in nodejs, are you? Using es6 as value for the module property in tsconfig.json it is not much of an option in that case. The import statement will fail to run in nodejs, unless you use flag --experimental-modules from nodejs 8+ and renaming your files to have extension .mjs. https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/esm.html#esm_ecmascript_modules. Has anyone solve this issue when running the code in nodejs?

Comment: It wasn't on nodejs.  I don't have an alternate solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

> while Paragraph_1.default is undefined.

This means the type definition:

```
declare module "grommet/components/Paragraph" {
   export default Grommet.Paragraph;
}
```

**is wrong**. This is just one of the many reasons I am not a fan of `default` : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/tips/defaultIsBad.html

## Fix

- Try not to use libraries *not written in TypeScript*
  especially since TypeScript [modules are super easy to write](https://egghead.io/lessons/typescript-create-high-quality-npm-packages-using-typescript).

Fix the type definition if you must:

```
 declare module "grommet/components/Paragraph" {
       export Paragraph: typeof Grommet.Paragraph;
 }
```

Comment: I did try this, however it generated compiler errors.